# Alternative to Intel C++ compiler for Windows and OSX, which provides CPU dispatching

Tags: windows, macos, compiler-optimization, intel-composer

I'm quite honestly sick of Intel compiler now, because it's just buggy, sometimes just generates incorrect crashing code, which is especially bad, since the compilation takes like 2 hours, so there's really no way to try to get around it. Profile guided optimizations, which are needed to make executables at least reasonably sized, always generate crashing code currently for me, so...

But it has one perk no other compiler I know has - dispatching to instruction sets, which is essential for my use - signal processing. Is there any other compiler, that can do that?

(for the record I'm even ok with "pragming" every loop, that would need the CPU dispatching, and no need for nonlooped operations probably)

Comment: Have you Googled for [*"gcc cpu dispatch"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=cpu+dispatch+gcc)?

Comment: Well, it seems that you can mark functions with instruction set, which could be useful, but for my case it would be just brutal... What ICC does is that it targets individual loops for vectorizing, which works great. No need to write a certain function many times etc. If the GCC's cpu dispatch is what I found it is, it doesn't seem too useful really.

Comment: I disagree with the premise that icpc is buggy but you can do automatic dispatching by using the `target_clones` function attribute in g++

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out. Anyways I actually solved multiple issues with ICPC generating invalid code leading to crashes. And now I have another one, hence my post...